# Too Many Redirects: passenger+nginx SSLRequirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger, ruby-on-rails-2

I have an old rails 2.3 app that I'm in the process of moving to nginx+Passenger (from Apache+Passenger). Nginx is configured for SSL and appears to be functioning correctly, except I am getting getting stuck in a 302 redirect loop from my Rails app.

The rails app thinks that the requests are not ssl (request.ssl? must be evaluating to false). In the production.log, each log entry shows the request as http. If I disable the SSLRequirement plugin, then the redirect loop goes away. However, I'd like to make sure my rails app is detecting an https request so that it can set the protocol correctly when I create absolute URLs.

The only reason I mention the previous Apache+Passenger setup is that the SSLRequirement plugin was functioning properly under that configuration.

The nginx config for my virtual host looks like this:

```
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  new.example.com;
  root /home/user/railsapps/example-setup/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/2013/example.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/2013/example.key;
  ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to your question but you appear to not be setting any of the standard proxy headers e.g. "proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" Not setting them may be produce 'exciting' behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:

[Error 310. Too many redirects with nginx + rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848549/error-310-too-many-redirects-with-nginx-rails-3?rq=1)

I simply needed to change the config to the following:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  server_name  new.usfamilytree.com;
  root /home/admin/railsapps/example-setup/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/2013/example.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/2013/example.key;
  ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
}
```

I removed the ssl off of the listen line and added the "ssl on;" line.

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed your Rails app isn't aware that the request is done via HTTPS. According [to this page](https://ariejan.net/2011/10/22/automatically-switch-between-ssl-and-non-ssl-with-nginx-unicorn-rails/) you need to set:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

To get Nginx to pass the scheme through to Rails

However they set it in the location block and you appear not to have one.

Comment: That's what I needed to make it work with unicorn as in this case nginx is acting as a proxy. I think it is different for passenger though.

Answer (score 0):

@Danack's answer won't work because passenger doesn't run as a proxy - it runs as a module to nginx. Instead, you can fake any http header with `passenger_set_cgi_param`.

```
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
```

I don't know if the X-Forwarded-Proto is standard for rails now, but it worked automatically with `request.ssl?` for me on rails 4.

[Docs here.](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_set_cgi_param_lt_cgi_environment_name_gt_lt_value_gt)

Comment: As of Passenger 5.0.1 `passenger_set_cgi_param` is [no longer available](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/) and replaced with `passenger_set_header`.